# Yosemite - Sleep Wake Failure - MBP Late 2013

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I have the following MBP which is currently running Yosemite V10.10.2

MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)
Processor: 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7
Memory: 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2048 MB

Ever since I upgraded to Yosemite I get persistent crashes when the machine wakes from sleeping. It's very intermittent, sometimes it'll be fine for days and others it will happen a few times per day. Either way it's very frustrating.

It results in the laptop simply being switched off when I reopen the lid and I have to start again by pressing the power button. Or it has rebooted already and is back at the login prompt. Again, there is no clear pattern when either of those happens though.

The applications I run every day and are usually open when it happens are Chrome and VMWare Fusion 7 running a single VM with Windows8. I also have iPhoto and Eclipse open more often than not.

I've searched the forum and a few people seem to be experiencing similar but not exactly the same symptoms. A search on the reported code doesn't return any results. I've tried a PRAM reset but I get the same behaviour.

Is there any way of diagnosing exactly what's causing this?

Many thanks,
Lee

The Problem Report lists the following details:

Date/Time:       2015-02-03 20:44:27 +0000
OS Version:      10.10.2 (Build 14C109)
Architecture:    x86_64h
Report Version: 21
Event:           Sleep Wake Failure
Steps:           1
Hardware model:  MacBookPro11,3
Active cpus:     8

================================================================
Code: 0x13006c00
Model: MacBookPro11,3, BootROM MBP112.0138.B14, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.3 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.19f12
Graphics: Intel Iris Pro, Intel Iris Pro, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M, PCIe, 2048 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, -
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, -
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x134), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.159.13.12)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.2f6 15235, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Thunderbolt Ethernet, Ethernet, en4
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
PCI Card: Apple 57762-A0, Ethernet Controller, Thunderbolt@195,0,0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0512F, 500.28 GB
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 17.1
Thunderbolt Device: Thunderbolt to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter, Apple Inc., 1, 5.5

NOTE: ALSO POSTED ON APPLE FORUM: https://discussions.apple.com/message/27605945#27605945